# 3d modeling for data structures

Tags: data-structures, modeling

I'm looking for a 3D modeling/animation software. Honestly, I don't know if this is something achievable - but what I want to have is some kind of visual representation of various ideas.

Speaking in future tense: if I were to read about of the boot process of an OS, I would visualize the various data structures building up; and I can step through the process with a sliding bar or so. If I were to think about a complex data structure, I would have a 3D representation of various links and relations between them. Another would be a Git repository at work - how commits/trees/blobs are linked in space, and how they progress as time passes. And all of these would be interactive.

The reason why I want to do this is that it'd be very easy to explain the process. Not just to others, but also to self. I can revisit my model, and it'd be a quick brush up.

I'm sure there are no ready-to-use softwares for this. What I could think of are Flash, with action scripting, or Blender 3D (Python scripting?); or Synfig. Whatever it's, I've to learn up start; and I'm looking for suggestions as to which (even if not in my list) is the right one to choose.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Blender, but it requires a large upfront investment of time, especially to learn the UI.  Blender is all about the hotkeys.  Once you have them memorized, it's great.  But getting there takes a while.

[Alice](http://www.alice.org/) might be worth a look.  It looks easy to use and supports scripting.

Comment: Alice sounds promising. Thanks for the suggestion.

My knowledge on Blender is practically nil. But what does Bleder's output look like? Is it readily usable? For example, Flash's output could be SWF, which you could view in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools available for 3D modeling. I'm a fan of 3D Studio max. But there is Blender, Maya, and truespace.

You may want to take a look at the field of visualization to help with illustrating your message.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that packages such as 3D Studio Max and Blender are too powerful, in the sense that your relatively simple requirements will force you on too long a learning path.  Try Googling for Data Structure Animations to get an idea of what others have used.  Also, head over to Information Aesthetics, they recently featured a tool for visualising commits and checkouts to/from repositories and similar.

My favourite is nearly the Lego Designer, very good for 3D block animations, but so far I haven't figured out how to add text to the blocks.